# Override modal view controller elevated background color?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-darkmode

When in dark mode and presenting a view controller modally (or popovers), even if the view's background color is say black, it gets overridden to the elevated system background color (a dark grey when in dark mode, white when in light mode).

```
// Still shows as dark grey when presented modally or in popover
self.view.backgroundColor = .black
```

Is it possible to override this behavior and let the original background color be shown (black instead of the elevated grey in dark mode)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! In order to override this behavior, you simply need to set             `definesPresentationContext` to `true` on the view controller being presented.

```
modalViewController.definesPresentationContext = true
```